# Used memory of my single page application increases as time goes

Tags: performance, google-chrome, memory-management, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools

We have a single page application, which runs well at the beginning, but slows down sharply as time goes. I am trying to investigate the root cause.

I use Chrome DevTool to record the timeline for initial page loading and a typical user operation. The JS Heap shows that the memory usage is ok: goes up and down periodically (due to Garbage Collection by browser, maybe).

However, when I check the Chrome Task Manager, I found that my page uses 60MB memory initially. But after 1 hour (and some user operations), the memory goes to 160MB. While the `JavaScript Memory` seems stable. Later I observed that the memory usage never goes down.

I guess maybe there is some memory leak in our JavaScript code? But the JS Heap seems ok. Does Chrome hold those memory and may release in future (when, say, other process needs more memory)?

Here is the Timeline recorded when I am operating:

[image]

I googled but cannot find explanations about this. Could anybody help? Thanks.

Comment: Please check whether you are using DOM Parser or Document Tree Structure in your view source page which may slow down your performance.

Comment: Would be better if you post your chrome-devtools results.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of an interval that is not cleared. It keeps calling a function too frequently.